# Deprecation warning in Rails 4 application (Hartl Tutorial)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, deprecation-warning

I am working through Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial and when I run my test suite I am seeing errors like this:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not explicitly
`true` or `false` to a boolean column. Currently this value casts to `false`. 
This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will cast to `true` in Rails 
5. If you would like to maintain the current behavior, you should explicitly 
handle the values you would like cast to `false`. (called from remember at  
.../RoR_Tutorial/sample_app/app/models/user.rb:28)

DEPRECATION WARNING: You attempted to assign a value which is not explicitly 
`true` or `false` to a boolean column. Currently this value casts to `false`. 
This will change to match Ruby's semantics, and will cast to `true` in Rails 
5. If you would like to maintain the current behavior, you should explicitly 
handle the values you would like cast to `false`. (called from update at     
...RoR_Tutorial/sample_app/app/controllers/users_controller.rb:40)
```

It seems to be angry about the calls to `update_attribute` such as this:

```
def remember
  self.remember_token = User.new_token
  update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
end
```

or

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
    flash[:success] = 'Profile Updated'
    redirect_to @user
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

...can anyone clarify what this warning is trying to tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out I had an error in my YAML file that was used to create my test users.

```
lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true,
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

...note that pesky comma at the end of the `activated:` line.  That meant that I was not actually setting the value to boolean `true` (guessing it views that as a string of 5 characters?).

By correcting the YAML to

```
lana:
  name: Lana Kane
  email: hands@example.gov
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
  activated: true
  activated_at: <%= Time.zone.now %>
```

...(no comma at the end of the `activated` line) the error goes away.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your database has some `boolean` type columns, which means their values is restricted to `true` or `false`. According to deprecation warnings, your calls to `update_attributes` and `update_attribute` in your `User` model and `users_controller` set those attributes' values to something different than `true` or `false` (although it gets casted to one of those two options anyways).

As long as you're following a tutorial, there seems nothing to be worried about: you've been warned that the algorighm of transformation of different values to `true` or `false` is going to be changed in the upcoming release of `Rails`.

Although Hartl's Tutorial might be a bit outdated, it still seems a little strange to me to see those type castings. You might want to double-check your `schema.rb` and migrations files with ones listed in the book to make sure your setup is absolutely correct.